# Schema.org availabilityEnds per day

Tags: schema.org, iso8601

Is there any way to setup [`availabilityEnds`](http://schema.org/availabilityEnds) for each day?

```
"offers": {
  "@type": "Offer",
  "availabilityStarts": "T17:00",
  "availabilityEnds": ["D6T22:00", "D7T22:00", "D1T21:00", "D2T21:00", "D3T21:00", "D4T21:00", "D5T21:00"]
},
```

Is that proper format for ISO 8601? So "D6T22:00" is every Saturday at 10pm?